# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.3 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

Due to this error, android studio can't `synchronize` grade and build my app

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

please how do i fix this?

Comment: could you add your gradle file code source

Comment: ok sir i have just work on this line of code and it synchronize implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the **support library** use

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

If you are using **androidx** library use.

```
implementation  'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to include this library

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

and this

```
repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems. As far as I understand MSAL released only for AndroidX but not for support library. 
Are there any plans to release it supporting Support Library ?